# XPath expression to verify a NodeList

Tags: java, xml, xpath, nodelist

I have a NodeList in Java and this XML file, (just a part of it)

if I have

```
<Book title="aaa" author="bbb" price="12" year="2011" />
```

I can use an XPath expression to see if some conditions are verified, for example:

```
local-name(.) = 'Book' and @title local-name(.) = 'Book' and @title
```

If the result of XPath expression execution is true...do something, otherwise do something else.
In this case I built an expression directly on a Node, and that's ok.

In the case of NodeList, how can I do the same task?
I would like to see if NodeList (org.w3c.NodeList in Java) has some nodes, for example, but using an XPath expression.

Thanks
Luca

Comment: Good question, +1. Yes, generally XPath can be used to select nodes from a given node-set, using a variable that contains the node-set or another XPath expression that selects the nodes of this node-set.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over nodes in the `NodeList` and apply your xpath to each node.

Answer (score 0):

If the node-set is in a variable `$v`, then the following XPath expression:

```
$v[self::Book and @title]
```

selects all nodes from `$v` that are `Book` elements and that also have an attribute named `title`.

If the node-set can be obtained as the result of evaluation a particular XPath expression, then you can substitute `$v` with this expression:

```
yourExpression[self::Book and @title]
```

For example, if the node-set in question consists of all nodes returned by `/*/*`, then one expression that selects the wanted nodes from this node-set is:

```
/*/*[self::Book and @title]
```